# Doctrine 2 Transaction demarcation: implicit vs explicit

Tags: transactions, doctrine-orm

Im reading the doctrine 2 docs and have a question about transaction demarcation.  Is there any difference between the following two snippets of code (other than syntax obviously)?  Or is this just two ways of doing the exact same thing (ie implicitly and explicitly).  What is the preferred method/best practice (implicit or explicit)?

Implicit:

```
// $em instanceof EntityManager
$user = new User;
$user->setName('George');
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Explicit:

```
// $em instanceof EntityManager
$em->transactional(function($em) {
    $user = new User;
    $user->setName('George');
    $em->persist($user);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](//docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) says:

> Explicit transaction demarcation is required when you want to include
>   custom DBAL operations in a unit of work or when you want to make use
>   of some methods of the EntityManager API that require an active
>   transaction. Such methods will throw a TransactionRequiredException to
>   inform you of that requirement.

In other cases there's no difference and you can use any of two (I'd prefer implicit to reduce noise).

Comment: how to pass custom arguments to function($em) if I try it breaks?

Comment: @blackuprise `function ($em) use ($yourargument) { $yourargument... }`